# How to avoid having to manually set application/json header for each http request?

Tags: angular

Currently, I have to call everything like this, manually having to add the correct header to each request (and also have to manually stringify it seems..?). Is there a place I can define standard headers to be used for the whole application?

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    constructor(private http:Http) {
    }

    doSomething(data:MyObj) {
        return this.http.post('/api/somebackend',
            JSON.stringify(data),
            {
                headers: new Headers({
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                })
            })
            .map(e => e.json())
            // ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question:

[How to make Angular 2 send all requests as application/x-www-form-urlencoded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34704654/how-to-make-angular-2-send-all-requests-as-application-x-www-form-urlencoded/34704819#34704819)

you can do the same just add the header `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry for posting as an answer but I don't have enough rep to comment.

you could try using an interceptor like it's shown [here](http://onehungrymind.com/winning-http-interceptors-angularjs/).
So you only define it in one place.

Comment: This question is for angular2