# POST works with JQuery but does not work with XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, post, xmlhttprequest

So I'm trying to POST to my server (php) from Javascript and am trying to not use JQuery.

This code works and posts the necessary data to the database

```
var msg = {};
msg['name'] = 'joe';
msg['message'] = 'why no work';

$.post(phpURL, msg, function(data) {});
```

but this one does not

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", phpURL, true);
xhr.send(msg);
```

I even looked at my php logs, looked at the headers and the only difference of the JQuery one from the XHR one I could see was the content-type header `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"` and this header `"x-requested-with" "XMLHttpRequest"`.

So I tried all combinations of the following headers.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", phpURL, true);
//xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
//xhr.setRequestHeader('x-requested-with', 'XMLHttpRequest');
xhr.send(msg);
```

to no effect.

It is worth mentioning if I try to add `JSON.stringify(msg)` anywhere, it does not work, neither in JQuery or XHR. But I would like to get this working first, and explain this bizarre difference.

I am inclined to believe this is a Javascript issue since the JQuery post works and in addition, a GET request of the server and the same table I'm trying to post to does work.

Comment: You've format the data to send to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format when sending a native XHR, jQuery does that automatically for you.

Comment: That thread above discusses data format

Comment: Yes thank you both, you are correct. If I change the msg to be 'name=bla&message=ble' it does work. I want to send as JSON though because I need to send utf8 but I guess that will have to be another question.

Comment: JSON is not an enctype. You need to set `Content-Type', 'text/plain; charset=UTF-8'` header, if you want to send JSON. The data reading on the server differs from the traditional handling in this case.

Comment: thank you for the help, it still doesn't work. The POST object is empty in my PHP code, I have no idea why

Comment: Like said earlier, "_data reading on the server differs from the traditional_". Read the value using `file_get_contents('php://input');`. It returns you the JSON as a string (providing you send a stringified object).

Comment: thank you very much, I didn't look at this answer but slept on this and after 6 hours of frustration yesterday this came to me this morning like a light in the darkness. I have actually done this before some years ago but just forgot ahaha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Do not confuse JavaScript objects with JSON](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/).

If you pass an object to jQuery's `data` parameter then it will encode it as `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data (not JSON!).

If you POST `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data to PHP then it will parse it and populate the `$_POST` superglobal with it.

If you pass an object to the `send()` method of an `XMLHttpRequest` object then it will **not** encode it for you. It will invoke `.toString()` on it implicit and send nothing very useful at all.

To achieve the same effect as jQuery will do then you need to [encode the data yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39786337/convert-json-object-data-to-x-www-form-urlencoded). Don't forget to also set the `Content-Type` header!

```
const encoded = new URLSearchParams(Object.entries(msg)).toString();
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", phpURL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.send(encoded);
```

---

If you want to send JSON then you also have to encode it, but that is done simply with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) although you also need to set the Content-Type header  (to `application/json` this time).

```
const encoded = JSON.stringify(msg);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", phpURL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xhr.send(encoded);
```

However, PHP **will not parse JSON automatically** so `$_POST` will remain empty, so you [need to parse it manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004783/reading-json-post-using-php).

```
<?php 
    $json = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $msg = json_decode($json);
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery does a lot of work under the hood when sending an AJAX request. It converts a live object in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format and fixes the headers, and does other tasks depending on the arguments.

When you're sending a native XMLHttpRequest, you've to handle all this by yourself. In the comments you said, you actually want to send JSON. JSON is not a standard form content type PHP would recognize, hence you've to send it in application/json format. Like this:

```
var msg = {
    name: 'joe',
    message: 'why no work'
  },
  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', phpURL, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
// Add response handling here, if needed
xhr.send(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

However, content type of application/json is not considered as form data in PHP, and `$_POST` will be empty. You can read the data from the received raw data, which is saved in a specific file. Like this:

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
// Results a string: '{"name":"joe","message":"why no work"}'
```

Now you can convert the JSON to associative array with `json_decode($data)`.

Comment: JSON is not plain text. The content-type for JSON is `application/json`

Comment: @Quentin ??? Technically JSON is plain text, I'll check `application/json`, just a second.

Comment: JSON is text, but it is formatted text, not plain text.

Comment: @Quentin I think PHP doesn't make a difference, but maybe some other languages will do?

Comment: If you don't write code to pay attention to what Content-Type you are sending, then it is pretty much irrelevant… but a bad practise that could trip you up in future (e.g.  if you later switch your backend and use a library to parse the incoming data (which pays attention to the content-type) instead of just assuming you'll be sent JSON.

Comment: @Quentin You're absolutely right. It looks like I've some job to do at the weekend, I've to fix a ton of requests sending JSON data on my sites.