# Ionic 2 login via django-registration view causes 403 error

Tags: python, django, ionic2, csrf, django-registration

I have trouble:

1. I've ionic 2 app, in which user need login via form
2. Django backend with django-registration for user registration/login/etc.

Problem: Sending data via post request to django-registration login url causes 403 Forbidden error(Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /accounts/login/). 
So, my opinion, that in this case I can't fix it without changing user authentication library on backend side. But I need use those stack and those libraries. Commenting csrf middleware in settings file doesn't help. I've been tried use angular2-cookie from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39438567/3342929) answer, but it's still returning 403 error. Is there another way to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried sending It with post man ? - If it fails with post-man then we know its django , If it is successful then we know it's ionic 2

Comment: Well, there is a problem with structure: we can't login without csrf token(in django-registration for login view uses LoginView from django.contrib.auth, which dispatch method decorated by @csrf_protect. So, in the end, we need change library for login(to rest-auth)