# Can we use angular 2 with django(with out using django rest framework)?

Tags: django, angular

I am in a middle of a project. I am done with models and basic request.
I wanted to use Angular but seems like integrating angular directly with Django is a tough task. Can I use Django directly if I return `JsonResponse` instead `og=f HttpResponse` or will it cause some troubles?

Comment: Using angular on the front end should have nothing to do with what back end you're using. What exactly do you mean when you say integrating angular with django is difficult?

Comment: Since template processor command ( {{ }} ) for variable is same in both, so I think it might cause the issue. i was refering to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34672987/django-with-angular-2 tis thread in which it is suggested to use rest framework.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11108407/2896976

Comment: You can use class based views in Django and front end angular 2.