# Angular2 and Django: CSRF Token Headache

Tags: python, django, angular, cors, csrf

**The Issue I'm Having**

- I'm making an Ajax POST request from my **Angular2** client to my **Django** (v1.9) backend (both on localhost, different ports). I'm not yet using the Django REST framework, I'm just dumping the JSON in Django without any add-ons.
- I have been issued a **csrf token** by the server, and I'm manually sending it back in the HTTP headers (I can see it there when I make the call).
- However, I still get the error from django: **Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)**
- I've read a number of other threads, and tried a few things, but still can't get Django to accept the CSRF token.

**Client side code:**

```
private _editUserUri = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/edit/user/";

constructor(private _http: Http){}

getCookie(name) {
    let value = "; " + document.cookie;
    let parts = value.split("; " + name + "=");
    if (parts.length == 2) 
      return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

validateData(userdata) {
    return true;
}

editUser(userdata) {

    console.log("UserService: createUser function called");
    console.log(JSON.stringify(userdata));

    if(this.validateData(userdata)) {

        let headers = new Headers({
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': this.getCookie('csrftoken')
        });

        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this._http
            .post(
                this._editUserUri,
                JSON.stringify(userdata),
                options)
            .map(res => {
                console.log(res.json());
                return res.json();
            })
    }

}
```

**Screenshot of csrf token in header (x-csrftoken). This is exactly how Django expects it** ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/csrf/))
[image: Screenshot]

**What I've tried / considered**

- I thought that perhaps the csrf token is out of date. I've tried to generate a new one, but I haven't yet managed to get Django to issue me a new one. I've tried using the @ensure_csrf_cookie decorator, but still nothing. If I have a csrf token in a cookie which was placed this morning, would I expect it to be replaced by a new, up-to-date version?
- Another thought was that the header name (x-csrftoken) is in lower case. Django specifies that the header name should be the following: **X-CSRFToken**. However, from reading online it seems that headers should generally be case sensitive. In any case, Angular2 is automatically converting the header name to lower case.
- I tried some other solutions I found on Stack Overflow ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494876/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-angular2-http-requests-with-django-csrf-protection)) but had no luck.
- I thought that maybe this was related to CORS, but the first OPTIONS request returns a 200 from my Django server. This pre-flight request wouldn't need to include the csrf token in its headers also, would it? (excuse my ignorance)
- I'm pretty sure my settings are fine. I have 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware' in MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES, **CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = False**, **CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True** and **CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True**

If anyone could help I'd greatly appreciate it!

Nick

Comment: You can try passing the token inside `csrfmiddlewaretoken` POST parameter. Not sure if header name is case sensitive, but you can check it by making a post request through something that doesn't convert it to lowercase (jquery perhaps).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the problem is that your request only has the CSRF token header, but not the cookie (see the [double submit](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#Double_Submit_Cookie) mitigation against CSRF, the header you're sending should be compared to the cookie).

I don't quite understand what exactly is happening though. If you elaborate a bit more on where the Angular app is downloaded from and how it gets the CSRF cookie from Django, which is a different origin, I can probably edit this answer to help more. What I don't get is that if the Angular app is downloaded from port A, from where does it have a CSRF cookie for Django on port B.

**Edit:**

Ah you're using CORS. I think you need `withCredentials` in the jQuery request so that the csrf cookie is sent with the request:

```
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
}
```

Django then needs to send `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` I think.

Comment: Hey lengyelg, thanks for your response. I'm running two servers on my localhost: one at 127.0.0.1:3000 (node.js angular2) hosting the angular app and another at 127.0.0.1:8000 (django). When I go to 127.0.0.1:3000 (or localhost:3000), I can see the cookie in the console (document.cookie) as well as in Chrome -> Settings -> Content Settings -> Cookies (csrftoken=xr0Yc7umZdkXEO2dbRrnYNMcHTH4zauT). My Angular app gets the token ID from this cookie. As far as I understand, Django sets the cookie in a response to a http request (and should it every time if @ensure_csrf_cookie is present).

Comment: Yep, the reason it doesn't work is I think CORS. You need to enable sending cookies in cross-origin requests by 1) adding Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true to the Django responses and 2) setting up jQuery to send cookies with cross-origin requests by setting withCredentials to true.
These two would I think help with the csrf cookie also being sent and it would all just work. :)

Comment: Thanks lengyelg, I'll give this a go a little later and let you know! Since I'm using Angular2 / typescript, I'll try to see if there's an inbuilt way of doing the second part (w/o having to get jQuery involved).

Comment: Fixed it! When I checked the network tab Django was indeed sending me the cookie on every response, but Angular wasn't sending the session and csrf cookies on request. I fixed it by adding **{ withCredentials: true }** to my RequestOptions object. Thanks, man!! (I can't +1 your response as I have less than 15 reputation, but confirmed as right answer)