# I am getting this error rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to upgrade my django 1.9 to django 2.0. It is working fine for GET() but I am getting error in POST(). 
My `views.py` is:-

```
class AccountInfoUpdate(APIView):
    authentication_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def post(self, request):
        user = request.user
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=user)
        name = False
        contact = False
        if "name" in request.data:
            user_profile.name = request.data.get('name')
            user_profile.save()
            name = True
        if "contact" in request.data:
            user_profile.contact = request.data.get('contact')
            user_profile.save()
            contact = True

        if user_profile.affiliate_code is not None and (name or contact):
            result = service.update_affiliate(user_profile.affiliate_code, name=user_profile.name,
                                                   contact=user_profile.contact)

        return Response({'Message': 'Account info updated successfully!'})
```

I am getting this error:-

```
user_auth_tuple = authenticator.authenticate(self)
rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'IsAuthenticated' object has no attribute 'authenticate'
```

If I removed or comment `'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',` from REST_FRAMEWORK then I am getting this error `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect`.

I tried `permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]` and did fallow on Postman but still getting same error.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**`IsAuthenticated`** is a `Permission Class` not an `Authentication` class. So it should be as

```
class AccountInfoUpdate(APIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    # your code
```

**UPDATE-1**
How to resolve `CSRF Failed` error
1. **Open a new tab in POSTMAN**
[image: POSTMAN Screenshot]
2. Provide URL(1)
3. Go to `Authorization` tab(2) and setect `Basic Auth` then provide your username and password
4. Then go to `Body` tab, and enter your JSON payload.
5. Hit `send` button. There you go

Comment: I tried it but its not working it given me this error `CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.`

Comment: Did you tried [these solutions](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=CSRF+Failed:+CSRF+token+missing+or+incorrect+site:stackoverflow.com&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiDprOP_KLcAhUDtI8KHSSBDKsQrQIoBDAAegQIABAN&biw=1366&bih=650)

Comment: Yes, but i am not getting anythings to resolved my problem I am getting same error.

Comment: Anyway can you show how you are posting the data, and your urls.py ?

Comment: my url.py is:- `url(r'^v1/account/info/update/$', AccountInfoUpdate.as_view()),`

Comment: and How you are POST your data?

Comment: Updated the answer. (**Point 1** is the mandatory step, don't miss it)

Comment: why Authorization? which username and password I need to put ? Its working without this when I hit GET(). Like login, only its not working when I tried to update user name in POST(). I am not getting logged in user through `request.user`. Its working fine in django 1.9

Comment: As I said erlier, you are added a `pemission_class` so, you have to put your credentials while accessing corresponding API. The choices of username and password to be used depends on you/your application, for instance you can use **superuser**'s username ans password there

Comment: In `Header` only Content-Type = application/json

Comment: In your screenshot, there are 3 entries...Can you show add the Headers screenshot?

Comment: That **Authorization** must be applied.

Comment: Mark the answer as *Accepted* if my answer helpfull

Answer (score 1):

I was also getting this error "rest_framework.request.WrappedAttributeError: 'IsAuthenticated' object has no attribute 'authenticate'" error in following manner:

my login code was having:

```
def post(self, request,):
        username = request.data.get("username")
        password = request.data.get("password")
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
```

While i was getting error, REST_FRAMEWORK contained following in settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    ),  
}
```

Later i added following also and my error was gone:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    ......
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )   
}
```

You can try and give feedback please.

Answer (score 0):

`"CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect."` problem is solved by front end site but still its not working in postman side. Anyway, my problem is solved frond-end side by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34494876/what-is-the-right-way-to-use-angular2-http-requests-with-django-csrf-protection) after long RND.